# How to code find and replace button using sql server 2008 & VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

My app is using datagridview to display data from sqlserver.
I am working on a button code that will enable the user to find and replace the entire column. Eg find Class1 and replace with Class2. 
something like `UPDATE students SET class = combo1.text with combo2,text WHERE%`

I am feeling too far from reality. How can this code work?[image]

Comment: What did you try? A hint: either using an orm (try entity framework) or using `System.Data.SqlClient`

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste this code (taken from msdn)

```
Public Sub ExecuteQuery(ByVal queryString As String, _
  ByVal connectionString As String)
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        command.Connection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

.......
and now when you need to execute you query write this

```
Dim cn as String 
Dim UpdateQry as String
cn = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\eDataba‌​se.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
UpdateQry =  "Update students SET class = '" + combo2.text + "' WHERE class = '" + combo1.text + "'"
ExecuteQuery(UpdateQry, cn)
```

hope this helps you.

regards

Comment: `Class2` should not be a literal but also a variable coming from `combo2.text`.

Comment: And the `SET` and `WHE`RE` clause should also be swappted. He wants to set `Combo2.Text` where `Combo1.Text`

Comment: ' Private Sub Btn19_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn19.Click
        cn = New SqlConnection
        cn.ConnectionString =
        "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\eDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"

        cn.Open()
        Dim UpdateQry As String =
    "Update students SET class = '" + Combo1.Text + "' WHERE class = '" + Combo2.Text + "'"

        cn.Close()

    End Sub 'Replace All'  The button click is doing nothing.

Comment: In layman's language, i want when the user to find from the database, text (in combobox1) and replace it with text (in combobox2) when they clicks the Replace all button.

Comment: Gone through your code. you've opened the connection, afterwards defined the string namely UpdateQry which has been assigned the string which you need to execute on the server. Now you need to execute that SQL string, which you are not doing. you've closed the connection without executing the string. I'm updating my answer again for you.

Comment: I am now getting this error: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\GtechsLab\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\eRegista\eRegista\bin\Release\eDataba‌​se.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: @ Henry Gathigira, please check your connection string.. problem is with connection string.. as per error... I dont think this can be the path of your database file.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set your class to the value of Combo2, where the value already matches the value of Combo1.

```
    "UPDATE students 
    SET class = "+combo2.text+"
    where class = "+combo1.text+" "
```